# Avoid repeat the same mixin in Sass

Tags: sass, mixins

I have this `Mixin` for `padding` utility:

Sass code:

```
$padding: (
    top: "top",
    right: "right",
    bottom: "bottom",
    left: "left",
    all: "all"
);

@mixin no-padding($map) {
    @each $padding-side, $side in $map {
        @if $side == 'all' {
            & {
                padding: 0 !important;
            }
        } @else {
            &-#{$side} {
                padding-#{$side}: 0 !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use of it:

```
.u-noPadding {
   @include no-padding($padding);
}
```

I want to use the same `Mixin` but now for `margin`, is there any solution to avoid repeating the same `mixin` and make a good use of best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@mixin no($type,$sides:null) {
    $i:0 !important;
    @if $sides == null {
        #{$type}:$i;
    } @else {
        @each $side in $sides { 
            #{$type}-#{$side}:$i;
        }
    }
}

.u-noPadding {
    @include no(padding, top left etc...);        // choose any side separated with a space
}
.u-noMargin {
    @include no(margin);                          // instead of 'all', type nothing
}
```

Like this? Your `$sides` will be stored in a temporary map automatically if your second parameter is set, no need extra map for this.
About the second parameter: If you want no sides, let it empty and all sides will have `0`. Similiar to your `'all'` idea.. it's shorter.

Comment: Love this solution, clean, readable and easy to understand, thank you!.